# How to print values above 75th percentile from series? Using quantile(pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

*Given a series(1,3,4,7,8,8,9), print all the elements that are above the 75th percentile.*

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a=np.array([1,3,4,7,8,8,9])
df=pd.Series(a)
print(df)
s=df.quantile([.75])
print(s)
```

Here I've done finding the value of the 75th percentile, but don't know to find the values above that percentile. Please help me to solve it.

Comment: `df[df>=df.quantile(0.75)]`?

Answer (score 1):

Add this line at the end, it should do the job `print(df[df>=s.values[0]])`

Answer (score 0):

```
s=df[df>= np.percentile(df, 0.75)]
```

Should do the trick.

As should

```
s = - (-df).quantile(0.25).
```